# Coherent FieldMax2 ActiveX .dll works in LabView but not in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, labview

I'm working on integrating a Coherent FieldMax2 (an optical power meter connected via USB) into an automated measurement program in Python. The only information the vendor provides are LabView examples (.vi's) and an ActiveX .dll (according to the documentation available).

From the LabView examples I can access the various functions available in the .dll.
So far I've tried variations of the following approach to connect to the power meter, in just the same way as in the LabView examples available:

```
import ctypes

mydll =ctypes.WinDLL("C:\Windows\System32\FieldMax2Lib.dll")

py_connect=mydll.fm2LibOpenDriver
py_connect.restype=c_int32
py_connect.argtypes=[c_int16]
response=py_connect(0) # arg 0 = 1 available power meter
print(response)
```

However, no matter how I go about it, I simply get the response '-1' which according to the limited documentation means the .dll-file cannot find any power meter.
The LabView block scheme can be found

[image: LabView block scheme]

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to go about the problem

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to reproduce this problem, my versions are:

**sys.version** : *v3.7.1rc2 [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]*

**ctypes.__version__** : *1.1.0*

**FieldMaxII** : *v3.3.2.9_rc1*

My code is using the dll from the installer directory:

```
import ctypes as c

mydll = c.WinDLL(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Coherent\FieldMaxII PC\Drivers\Win10\FieldMax2Lib\x64\FieldMax2Lib.dll')

py_connect=mydll.fm2LibOpenDriver
py_connect.restype=c.c_int32
py_connect.argtypes=[c.c_int16]
response=py_connect(0) # arg 0 = 1 available power meter
print(response)
```

And is returning '0', additional communication/readout of the `FieldMaxII` is also possible.